# How to uncheck a checkbox after returning to a page

Tags: xamarin.forms

i have a checkboxes that i am setting in View Model and i am collecting user decision on a list, however once i filter my items and then go bakc on the page the checkbox is still checked even thought the list is empty so if i press again button to show filtered items i get nothing. I am clearing my list but i am not sure how to get the checkboxes unchecked once i come back. I have Mode = two way

```
 private bool _filterBeginnerItems = false;
        private bool _filterIntermediateItems = false;
        private bool _filterAdvancedItems = false;
        private bool _filterUpperIntermediateItems = false;

     public bool FilterBeginnerItems
            {
                set
                {
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                    _filterBeginnerItems = value;


                    if (_filterBeginnerItems)
                    {
                        FilterAllItems = false;

                        UserDecision.Add(_parentCategoryId = 1);
                    }

                }
                get => _filterBeginnerItems;
            }

            public bool FilterIntermediateItems
            {
                set
                {
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                    _filterIntermediateItems = value;


                    if (_filterIntermediateItems)
                    {
                        FilterAllItems = false;
                        UserDecision.Add(_parentCategoryId = 2);

                    }
                }
                get => _filterIntermediateItems;
            }
            public bool FilterUpperIntermediateItems
            {
                set
                {
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                    _filterUpperIntermediateItems = value;


                    if (_filterUpperIntermediateItems)
                    {
                        FilterAllItems = false;
                        UserDecision.Add(_parentCategoryId = 3);
                    }

                }
                get => _filterUpperIntermediateItems;
            }

 public FilterArticlesForPurchaseViewModel(INavigation navigation)
            : base()
        {


            Task.Run(async () => await LoadAllDataForArticlesAndCategories()).Wait();


            FilterItemsCommand = new Command(async () => navigation.PushAsync(new ArticlesForPurchaseFiltered()));

            UserDecision.Clear();
            //FilterAdvancedItems = false;
           // FilterBeginnerItems = false;

        }
```

Have tried to set their value to false but it doesnt help.

Comment: you should clear and reset any filter variables before you navigate to the new page

Comment: i have tried this //FilterAdvancedItems = false;
           // FilterBeginnerItems = false; but it didnt help i still had my checkboxes set

Comment: why are you calling NotifyPropertyChanged **before** you set the value of your properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I write a demo about clear the `CheckBox`

Here is running gif.

[image]

Here is `FilterArticlesForPurchaseViewModel.cs` to achieve the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. I used a `Command` to clear these checkbox.

```
   public class FilterArticlesForPurchaseViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _filterBeginnerItems = true;
        private bool _filterIntermediateItems = false;
        private bool _filterAdvancedItems = false;
        private bool _filterUpperIntermediateItems = false;

        public bool FilterBeginnerItems
        {
            set
            {
               // NotifyPropertyChanged();
                _filterBeginnerItems = value;

                OnPropertyChanged("FilterBeginnerItems");
                //if (_filterBeginnerItems)
                //{
                //    FilterAllItems = false;

                //    UserDecision.Add(_parentCategoryId = 1);
                //}

            }
            get => _filterBeginnerItems;
        }

        public bool FilterIntermediateItems
        {
            set
            {
              //  NotifyPropertyChanged();
                _filterIntermediateItems = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FilterIntermediateItems");

                //if (_filterIntermediateItems)
                //{
                //    FilterAllItems = false;
                //    UserDecision.Add(_parentCategoryId = 2);

                //}
            }
            get => _filterIntermediateItems;
        }
        public bool FilterUpperIntermediateItems
        {
            set
            {
               // NotifyPropertyChanged();
                _filterUpperIntermediateItems = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FilterUpperIntermediateItems");

                //if (_filterUpperIntermediateItems)
                //{
                //    FilterAllItems = false;
                //    UserDecision.Add(_parentCategoryId = 3);
                //}

            }
            get => _filterUpperIntermediateItems;
        }
        public ICommand ClearCommand { protected set; get; }
        public FilterArticlesForPurchaseViewModel(INavigation navigation)
        {
            ClearCommand = new Command(async () =>
            {
                FilterBeginnerItems = false;
                FilterIntermediateItems = false;
                FilterUpperIntermediateItems = false;


            });
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is layout.xaml

```
    <StackLayout>
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding FilterBeginnerItems,Mode=TwoWay}"></CheckBox>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding FilterIntermediateItems,Mode=TwoWay}"></CheckBox>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding FilterUpperIntermediateItems,Mode=TwoWay}"></CheckBox>

        <Button Text="clear" Command="{Binding ClearCommand}"></Button>

    </StackLayout>
```

Here is background code.

```
 public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.BindingContext = new FilterArticlesForPurchaseViewModel(Navigation);
        }
```

**=================update===================**

I make edit your viewmodel. Here is code, I achieve the remove data from the `List<int> UserDecision`

```
    public class FilterViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private bool _filterAllItems = true;
        private bool _filterBeginnerItems = false;
        private bool _filterIntermediateItems = false;
        private bool _filterAdvancedItems = false;
        private bool _filterUpperIntermediateItems = false;
        private static List<Article> _allArticlesForPurchase;
        private static List<Category> _allCategories;
        private static List<CategoryGroup> _allUserCategoryGroups;
        public static List<int> UserDecisionResult { get; set; }
        private static int _parentCategoryId;
        public ICommand FilterItemsCommand { get; private set; }
        public static List<int> UserDecision { get; set; } = new List<int>();
        public  bool FilterAllItems
        {
            set
            {

                _filterAllItems = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();

                if (FilterAllItems == false)
                {
                    if (UserDecision.Contains(_parentCategoryId = -1))
                    {
                        UserDecision.Remove(_parentCategoryId = -1);
                    }
                }

                if (FilterAllItems == true)
                {
                    FilterBeginnerItems = false;
                    FilterIntermediateItems = false;
                    FilterUpperIntermediateItems = false;
                    FilterAdvancedItems = false;
                    if (!UserDecision.Contains(_parentCategoryId = -1))
                    {
                        UserDecision.Add(_parentCategoryId = -1);
                    }


                    if (UserDecision.Contains(_parentCategoryId=1))
                    {
                        UserDecision.Remove(_parentCategoryId = 1);
                    }
                    if (UserDecision.Contains(_parentCategoryId = 2))
                    {
                        UserDecision.Remove(_parentCategoryId = 2);
                    }
                    if (UserDecision.Contains(_parentCategoryId = 3))
                    {
                        UserDecision.Remove(_parentCategoryId = 3);
                    }
                    if (UserDecision.Contains(_parentCategoryId = 4))
                    {
                        UserDecision.Remove(_parentCategoryId = 4);
                    }

                }

            }
            get => _filterAllItems;
        }

        public bool FilterBeginnerItems
        {
            set
            {
                _filterBeginnerItems = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();

                if (_filterBeginnerItems)
                {
                    FilterAllItems = false;
                    UserDecision.Add(_parentCategoryId = 1);
                    if (UserDecision.Contains(_parentCategoryId = -1))
                    {
                        UserDecision.Remove(_parentCategoryId = -1);
                    }

                }

            }
            get => _filterBeginnerItems;
        }

        public bool FilterIntermediateItems
        {
            set
            {
                _filterIntermediateItems = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();

                if (_filterIntermediateItems)
                {
                    FilterAllItems = false;
                    UserDecision.Add(_parentCategoryId = 2);
                    if (UserDecision.Contains(_parentCategoryId = -1))
                    {
                        UserDecision.Remove(_parentCategoryId = -1);
                    }
                }

            }
            get => _filterIntermediateItems;
        }
        public bool FilterUpperIntermediateItems
        {
            set
            {
                _filterUpperIntermediateItems = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();

                if (_filterUpperIntermediateItems)
                {
                    FilterAllItems = false;
                    UserDecision.Add(_parentCategoryId = 3);
                    if (UserDecision.Contains(_parentCategoryId = -1))
                    {
                        UserDecision.Remove(_parentCategoryId = -1);
                    }
                }

            }
            get => _filterUpperIntermediateItems;
        }

        public bool FilterAdvancedItems
        {
            set
            {
                _filterAdvancedItems = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();

                if (_filterAdvancedItems)
                {
                    FilterAllItems = false;
                    UserDecision.Add(_parentCategoryId = 4);
                    if (UserDecision.Contains(_parentCategoryId = -1))
                    {
                        UserDecision.Remove(_parentCategoryId = -1);
                    }
                }

            }
            get => _filterAdvancedItems;
        }

        public FilterViewModel()
        {
            FilterItemsCommand = new Command(async () => await FilterItems());
            FindAllArticlesForPurchase();
        }
        public ObservableCollection<Article> FilterArticlesForPurchase { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Article>();




        private static void FindAllArticlesForPurchase()
        {
            foreach (var userDecision in UserDecision)
            {
                if (userDecision != -1)
                {
                    if (UserDecision.Count > 1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("more than one item");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("one item");
                    }


                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("not minus one");
                }
            }
        }



            private async Task FilterItems()
        {

            await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new Filter());
        }


    }
```

If you want to binding same `FilterViewModel` in `MainPage` and `Filter` page.
You should use static `FilterViewModel`  in the  `MainPage.xaml.cs`

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public static FilterViewModel filterViewModel ;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            filterViewModel= new FilterViewModel();
            BindingContext = filterViewModel;
        }
    }
```

In `Filter` page.You can binding same `FilterViewModel` in `MainPage.xaml.cs`

```
    public partial class Filter: ContentPage
    {
        public Filter()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            BindingContext = MainPage.filterViewModel;


            //If this FilterAllItems is empty, you want AllItems the checkbox to unselect, just set the value to false, the checkbox will update in the MainPage
            MainPage.filterViewModel.FilterAllItems = false;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213751/discussion-on-answer-by-leon-lu-msft-how-to-uncheck-a-checkbox-after-returning).